# Adding selected items from listview to another listview

Tags: c#, json, listview

I want to add every processed `SelectedItem` from `ListView A` to `ListView B` as a kind of a history.
It is working if I only coding this for only one object but when I am trying to add another object to the `ListView B` it is showing nothing. I know I have to deserialize this as a `List<obj>` but it is not working. Can you help me out?

This is what I tried so far:

```
// ListView A (Source)
// the ItemSelected is processed this function is called

public void AddToHistory(Object obj)
{
    string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "history.txt");
    var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
    File.WriteAllText(fileName, content);
}

// ListView B (Destination View)
void CreateListOfObjects()
{
    ObjectList = new List<Object>();
    string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "history.txt");
    var content = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
    var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object>(content);
    ObjectList.Add(json);
}

private List<Object> _object;
public List<Object> ObjectList
{
    get => _object;
    set => SetValue(ref _object, value);
}
```

Comment: where are Listview A and ListView B
how far are you getting in your code?

Comment: Not far. Thats it. I want to store these objects in a local txt file and use this as the ItemsSource of ListView B

Comment: not clear from your code where you are having a problem

Comment: My Problem is that I want add more than one object to LV B and I dont know how.

Comment: I dont see any listviews in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try using  File.AppendAllText instead of File.WriteAllText as WriteAllText will overwrite the exiting file while writing.

```
public void CreateListOfObjects()
    {
        string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "history.txt");
        var content = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
        var itemList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(content);
        foreach(var item in itemList)
        {
            listView2.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yep I did. The problem is that the objects appended will not be separated as a array. I am working on this right now. One moment.

Comment: Update code to fetch string array from txt and  display in listview. hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I found finally a workaround.
Now I am working with a List in the first place to have the wrapper for my object array.

```
// ListView A (Source)
// when ItemSelected is processed this function is called

public void AddToHistory(Object obj)
{
    string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "history.txt");
    var _tempList = new List<Object>();
    if (File.Exist(fileName) 
    {
        var _tempContent = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Object>>(tempContent);
        _tempList.AddRange(json);
        _tempList.Add(obj);
    } else 
    {
        _tempList.Add(obj);
    }
    var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_tempList);
    File.WriteAllText(fileName, content);
}

// ListView B (Destination View)
void CreateListOfObjects()
{
    ObjectList = new List<Object>();
    string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "history.txt");
    var content = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
    var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Object>>(content);
    ObjectList.AddRange(json);
}
```